# How do I determine JavaScript API for Office Version Number (App for Office 2013 Project)

Tags: c#, javascript, visual-studio-2013, office365, office-app

When creating a new Visual Studio 2013 "App for Office 2013" project, how do I determine what version the JavaScript API for Office is?  I see examples at Microsoft's website...

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn482498(v=office.1501401).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn482498%28v=office.1501401%29.aspx)

... but I am missing "goToByIdAsync" as an option, and wondering if it is a JavaScript API version concern.  The version specified in the URL example above is 1.1.

At any rate, given Microsoft has opted to version the API, there must be a way to identify the current version in a project....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - well I found what I believe is the answer.  I performed the following steps to identify a version number...

1. In the solution explorer, I highlighted the solution entry
2. Clicked menu item 'Tools'->'Library Package Manager'->'Manage NuGet
   Packages for Solution...'
3. Selected 'Office Javascript API'
4. Examined the right hand column field 'Version' and see 1.0.1

Searching NuGet, I see a newer version - version 1.1.0.3 is available.  I installed this version, and find it has the goToByIdAsync option....

The following URL shows the changes between version 1.0 and 1.1, including the addition of goToByIdAsync...

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn609936(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn609936%28v=office.15%29.aspx)